# Searching for a specific element in a TreeSet

Tags: java

I am attempting to search for Member with a specific regNumber within a TreeSet. The regNumber however doesn't have anything to do with the order of the elements in the TreeSet , which are ordered by last/first name.

The way I'm trying to do it now is to iterate through all the elements in TreeSet and return the element that matches the regNumber I am looking for. Is that good practice or is it too inefficient?

```
public class Members implements Comperable <Members> {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int regNumber;

}
```

P.S the elements in the TreeSet must remain ordered by last/first name

Comment: It is not a good practise but if all these are requirements for you, you can not do any other thing.

Comment: Your question raises further questions of how you're planning to use Collections. In particular, why are you using a TreeSet? If you want to find the Member with a specific regNumber, why not put them in a map (assuming regNumber is unique)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That fact that you are indexing by name and then searching by `regNumber` means that from the point of view of the `regNumber` you have an unordered collection of items. Therefore, you cannot do better than a linear search over all the items.

If you want something better you could use the `regNumber` as a key in a hash table (`HashMap` or whatever) and have a reference to the original `Member` object as value. That way you can search more efficiently at the cost of using more space.

Comment: +1 on using the regNumber as a hash key. If you need to lookup by either reg or by name, consider using a Bidirectional map (or two separate hashmaps).

Comment: Or `TreeMap`, if there was a reason for using `TreeSet`.